# Postgres/TCL flavour Regex: Negate a match using lookarounds

Tags: regex, postgresql, regex-lookarounds

I have a query where I would like to match a specific substring. As an example, let's match all entries with the word 'rice':

```
# select name from menus where name ~* 'rice' order by price limit 3;
         name
----------------------
 Rice Veges
 1/2 Rice 1/2 Githeri
 1/2 Rice 1/2 Chapo
(3 rows)
```

A more specific match also works. Note the addition of the 1/2

```
 select name from menus where name ~* '(1/2) rice' order by price limit 3;
         name
----------------------
 1/2 Rice 1/2 Githeri
 1/2 Rice 1/2 Chapo
 1/2 Rice 1/2 Matoke
(3 rows)
```

So, let's say I want to select all rice but I do not want entries with the 1/2 in it.

In essence, I want Set(Rice) - Set(1/2 Rice). My angle of attack here is to use a look around that will be negated.

```
# select name from menus where name ~* '(?!1/2) rice' order by price limit 3;
         name
----------------------
 1/2 Rice 1/2 Chapo
 1/2 Rice 1/2 Githeri
 1/2 Rice 1/2 Matoke
```

As you can see the expression above fails to work since it is still matching the substring 1/2

```
# select name from menus where name ~* '(?!2)\s*rice' order by price limit 3;
         name
----------------------
 Rice Veges
 1/2 Rice 1/2 Githeri
 1/2 Rice 1/2 Chapo
```

Simplifying the expression to remove the '1/' which might be causing issues due to improperly escaped strings doesn't yield what we want.

We can confirm that negative lookarounds are supported:

```
# select name from menus where name ~* '(?!r)ice' order by price limit 3;
      name
-----------------
 Juice Container
 Mango Juice
 Passion Juice
```

That is matching any string that has 'ice' but is not preceded by an 'r'.

Comment: `(?!r)ice` = `ice` as `i` is not equal to `r`. You actually want to use `'(?<!1/2 )rice'` where `(?<!1/2 )` is a negative lookbehind that fails the match if its pattern matches the text immediately to the left of the current position.

Comment: Interesting... I didn' know about the '<' in lookarounds. That seems to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `(?!r)ice` = `ice` as `i` is not equal to `r`. The `(?!r)` is a negative *lookahead* that fails the match if its pattern matches the text immediately to the *right* of the current position.

You actually want to use `'(?<!1/2 )rice'` where `(?<!1/2 )` is a negative lookbehind that fails the match if its pattern matches the text immediately to the left of the current position.

[PostgreSQL demo](https://rextester.com/HESH36483):

```
CREATE TABLE tb1
    (s character varying)
;

INSERT INTO tb1
    (s)
VALUES
    ('Rice Veges'),
    ('1/2 Rice 1/2 Githeri')
;

SELECT * FROM tb1 WHERE s ~* '(?<!1/2 )rice';
```

Result:

[image]

To match `1` as a whole word, add a `\y` word boundary, `'(?<!\y1/2 )rice'` (e.g. if you want `11/2 Rice 1/2 Githeri` to be returned).

Comment: Thanks Wiktor! This addresses my issue.